# How to change styles of a parent element of a <NavLink> tag in React.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

[image: Navbar]

I want to change the list-items' background-color property, when the chosen NavLink is active. From the docs I learned, that for adding an additional class to a **NavLink**, when it is active, I can use **activeClassName** prop, for making what I want, I need a parent selector in css, which don't exist.

**How to choose the parent element of the NavLink tag, when it has an *active class*?**

I need the green background only on the list-item with an active child NavLink.

```html
<ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="navItem">
           <NavLink className="navlink text-dark" activeStyle={{color: "#fff !important"}} to="/" exact>about</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
           <NavLink className="navlink text-dark" activeStyle={{color: "#fff !important"}} to="/services">services</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
           <NavLink className="navlink text-dark" activeStyle={{color: "#fff !important"}} to="/contacts">contacts</NavLink>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way would probably be to apply a state to your parent element to achieve this effect, which i.e. could represent the name of a CSS class for your parent. You can change this state depending on the active route or the clicked item to apply a new CSS class.

[**See working example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/312006/)

**Your parent class could look like this:**

```
import React from 'react'
import NavLink from './NavLink'

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      navbarClass: "navbar"
    }
  }

  setBgClass (title) {
    this.setState({
      navbarClass: `navbar navbar-${title}`
    })  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.navbarClass}>

        <NavLink 
          className="nav-item" 
          onClick={() => this.setBgClass('about')} 
          href='/about/'>
            About
        </button>

        <NavLink 
          className="nav-item" 
          onClick={() => this.setBgClass('services')} 
          href='/services/'>
            Services
        </button>

        <NavLink 
          className="nav-item" 
          onClick={() => this.setBgClass('contact')} 
          href='/contact/'>
            Contact
        </button>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

After that you only have to define appropriate CSS classes in your components stylesheet:

```
.navbar-about { background: green; }
.navbar-services { background: blue; }
.navbar-contact { background: orange; }
```

**NOTE:** 
If you call actual routes within your application i.e. using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), you may want to change the state of your parent navbar depending on your active route on `componentDidMount` instead of `onClick`, since the component may remount when the route changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :) I think I solved the problem, even without the parent selector, just by changing the padding of the <NavLink> tag. I read your option, seems very much like working, I'll mark it :) 
The important part is, that I wanted to solve the issue without js.